# Dynamic dependent dropdown menu Jquery without database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a dynamic dependent dropdown select menu with country, state and city only with jquery/javascrip and HTML, but when the country is selected the options go directly to the city and I already saw a lot of tutorials, the problem is that I don't want to use a database, I want to create the objects directly, if somebody could help me, here is my code:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var countries = {
        'mexico': [{
            display: "Ciudad de Mexico",
            value: "mx-city"
        }, {
            display: "Jalisco",
            value: "jalisco"
        }],
            'usa': [{
            display: "Texas",
            value: "texas"
        }, {
            display: "Ohio",
            value: "ohio"
        }],
            'canada': [{
            display: "Montreal",
            value: "montreal"
        }, {
            display: "Toronto",
            value: "toronto"
        }]
    };
     

     var states = {
        'mx-city': [{
            display: "Benito Juarez",
            value: "benito-juarez"
        }, {
            display: "Cuauhtemoc",
            value: "cuauhtemoc"
        }],
            'jalisco': [{
            display: "Zapopan",
            value: "zapopan"
        }, {
            display: "Guadalajara",
            value: "Guadalajara"
        }],
            'texas': [{
            display: "San Antonio",
            value: "san-antonio"
        }, {
            display: "Austin",
            value: "austin"
        }],
           'ohio': [{
            display: "Colombus",
            value: "colombus"
        }, {
            display: "Cleveland",
            value: "cleveland"
        }],
            'montreal': [{
            display: "Quebec",
            value: "Quebec"
        }, {
            display: "Vermont",
            value: "vermont"
        }],
            'toronto': [{
            display: "Ontario",
            value: "ontario"
        }, {
            display: "York",
            value: "york"
        }]
    };
   



           $("#parent_selection").change(function() {
            var parent = $(this).val();
             if (countries[parent] == undefined) {
            return $("#child_selection").html('Selecciona tu Estado');
           }
            list(countries[parent]);
  
           });



            function list(array_list){
              $("#child_selection").html(""); 
                 $(array_list).each(function (i) { 
                 $("#child_selection").append('<option value="'+array_list[i].value+'">'+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
           });
            }
   


            $('#child_selection').change(function() {
               var state = $(this).val();
   
               if (states[state] == undefined) {
               return $("#child").text('Selecciona tu ciudad');
             }
                list(states[state]);
              });

                  function list(array_list){
                    $("#child").html(""); 
                    $(array_list).each(function (i) { 
                     $("#child").append('<option value="'+array_list[i].value+'">'+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
           });
            }
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method=""  enctype="application/json">
    <br/>Nombre: <input type="text" />
    <br/>Edad:   <input type="text" />
    <br/>Pais:
    <select name="parent_selection" id="parent_selection">
      <option value="">Selecciona tu pais</option>
      <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
    </select>
    <br />Estado:
    <select name="child_selection" id="child_selection">
      <option value="">Selecciona tu estado</option>
    </select>
    <br/>Ciudad:
    <select name="child" id="child">
      <option value="">Selecciona tu ciudad</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake i found was a function called "list" this name are reserved.
- So change the name of function something like... getList().

The second mistake was when you want to call a value of this object.

This load the states dropdown :

```
   function getList(listCountries) {
       $("#child_selection").html(""); 
         $(listCountries).each(function (i) { 
           var arrayStates = states[listCountries[i]['value']];
           $.each(arrayStates,function(i){
             $("#child_selection").append('<option value="'+arrayStates[i]['value']+'">'+arrayStates[i]['display']);
           }); 
        });
    }
```

This load the cities of a country :

```
$('#child_selection').change(function() {
           var state = $(this).val();       
           var parent = $("#parent_selection").val();

             if (countries[parent] == undefined) {
               //DO SOMETHING
             } else {
               var listCountries = countries[parent];
                $(listCountries).each(function (i) { 
                  var arrayStates = states[listCountries[i]['value']];
                   $.each(arrayStates,function(i){
                     if ( state === arrayStates[i]['value'] ) {
                       $("#child").html("");
                       $("#child").append('<option value="'+listCountries[i]['value']+'">'+listCountries[i]['display']+'</option>');
                     }
                   });
                });
             }
          });
```

This is the code completly functional add it after declaration of states , check it and enjoy it:)

```
$("#parent_selection").change(function() {
        var parent = $(this).val(); 
         if (countries[parent] == undefined) {
            return $("#child_selection").html('Selecciona tu Estado');
       }

        getList(countries[parent]);

       });

        function getList(listCountries) {
           $("#child_selection").html(""); 
             $(listCountries).each(function (i) { 
               var arrayStates = states[listCountries[i]['value']];
               $.each(arrayStates,function(i){
                 $("#child_selection").append('<option value="'+arrayStates[i]['value']+'">'+arrayStates[i]['display']+'</option>');
               }); 
            });
        }



        $('#child_selection').change(function() {
           var state = $(this).val();       
           var parent = $("#parent_selection").val();

             if (countries[parent] == undefined) {
               //DO SOMETHING
             } else {
               var listCountries = countries[parent];
                $(listCountries).each(function (i) { 
                  var arrayStates = states[listCountries[i]['value']];
                   $.each(arrayStates,function(i){
                     if ( state === arrayStates[i]['value'] ) {
                       $("#child").html("");
                       $("#child").append('<option value="'+listCountries[i]['value']+'">'+listCountries[i]['display']+'</option>');
                     }
                   });
                });
             }
          });
```

My last tip:
Read something about how to do this with ajax will be better than this method to do it.

Comment: Hi! Joel! Thank you so much for your help, now the problem is that after choosing Mexico for example it loads the cities in the state and the state in the city, but as you said I'm gonna try to do it with Ayax, if you know a tutorial to do it it would be much appreciated! Thank you again :)

Comment: [Exemple codepen](http://codepen.io/SirXplosiv/pen/GWrNMB) funciona tal y como esperabas sino me equivoco , i mean , when you choose a country , load the states dropdown then choosed a state, load the city automatically